# Javascript onclick functions do not work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function setFont() {
   var i;
   for ( i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
      document.all[i].style.fontFamily = "Verdana";
      document.all[i].style.fontSize = "16";
      document.all[i].style.color="black";
   }
};


function abc(a) {
    alert(a);
    ansArray = ['a'];
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        document.write('<input type = "button" value = "a">');
        document.write('<input type = "button" value = "b">');
    }
    var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    //alert(myButton.length);
    myButton[0].onclick = function() {
        if (ansArray[0] == 'a') myButton[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        else myButton[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };
    myButton[1].onclick = function() {
        if (ansArray[0] == 'b') myButton[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        else myButton[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };
};​

setFont();
</script>
</head>

<body onload="Javascript:abc(2)">
hello
</body>
</html>
```

The onclick functions do not work in IE but work fine in chrome and firefox. I could not find the mistake. Why a normal function does not work. function loads the contents but onclicking the first two buttons for which event handelers are writen does not change the button colour in IE only. Please help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem might be scope of the `ansArray[0]` variable. Try declaring it as a global variable at the top of the script.

Comment: @GeekNum88 That's not it. He's only accessing `ansArray` within the `abc()` function. You may be confused by his poor formatting.

Comment: I'm working on this as well and I'm a little baffled by it. Any arrays declared are completely ignored. I.e. even those made outside of that function.

Comment: @Barmar much better (formatting).... I think that `ansArray` is reset every time - but this is very confusing....can we get an overview of what you are trying to do and maybe have a solution that is completely different code?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you don't need `javascript:` in `onXXX` handlers. Your whole approach in this application seems to be based on 10-year-old Javascript tutorials.

Comment: ansArray getting the value in fact there is a php part which assigns the value it is all right, but the first two buttons onclicking does not change the colou. In chrome and firefox no problem, Why IE getting the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that using `document.write` apparently overwrites JavaScript as well. If you switch your `document.write()` to `document.body.innerHTML +=` your problem is solved. Your latter two buttons won't work with that code because you are calling button `0` and `1` exclusively, while those second two are `3` and `4`.

Comment: He said "first two buttons for which event handlers are written". So he's not expecting the second pair to have handlers.

Comment: @Barmar I hadn't noticed that, but my answer is still the correct assessment and solution to his problem.

Comment: Give some idea to have buttons using document.body.innerHTML +=

Comment: @user1767304 I think you're asking me how to implement it. If so: replace `document.write('<input type = "button" value = "a">');` with `document.body.innerHTML += '<input type = "button" value = "a">'`

Answer (score 0):

quick googling suggests that the problem is that you are using document.write after the page has been loaded so it is erasing the dom as well. you should avoid using that in functions that are called after page loading.

source :   http://sitr.us/2012/09/04/monkey-patching-document-write.html

I dont have IE so couldn't test it.